# Query to show latest posts (not only posts, but also pages)

Tags: wordpress

I use both post and pages to write new content (pages to content related to companies we have already presented in the web (investment website) and post to unrelated events. I am trying to code a simple query that allows me to show the latest content including both pages and post created, but I do not know how to do that & not found information related.

I assume that post_type = 'page', 'post', but I am quite a beginner and lack of knowledge to code the complete query

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the array of post types to your query like this:

```
$args = array('post_type' => array( 'page', 'post' )); 
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```